# Packing record length in 2 bytes

Tags: c#, .net, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I want to create a ASCII string which will have a number of fields. For e.g.

```
string s = f1 + "|" + f2 + "|" + f3;
```

f1, f2, f3 are fields and "|"(pipe) is the delimiter. I want to avoid this delimiter and keep the field count at the beginning like:

```
string s = f1.Length + f2.Length + f3.Length + f1 + f2 + f3;
```

All lengths are going to be packed in 2 chars, Max length = 00-99 in this case. I was wondering if I can pack the length of each field in 2 bytes by extracting bytes out of a short. This would allow me to have a range 0-65536 using only 2 bytes. E.g.

```
short length = 20005;
byte b1 = (byte)length;
byte b2 = (byte)(length >> 8);
// Save bytes b1 and b2

// Read bytes b1 and b2
short length = 0;
length = b2;
length = (short)(length << 8);
length = (short)(length | b1);
// Now length is 20005
```

What do you think about the above code, Is this a good way to keep the record lengths?

Comment: If each field has max length of 99, then one byte would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see what you are trying to achieve. `short` aka `Int16` is 2 bytes - yes, so you can happily use it. But creating a string does not make sense.

```
short sh = 56100; // 2 bytes
```

I believe you mean, **being able to output** the `short` to a stream. For this there are ways:

- `BinaryWriter.Write(sh)` which writes 2 bytes straight to the stream
- `BitConverter.GetBytes(sh)` which gives you bytes of a `short`

Reading back you can use the same classes.

Comment: For example, If I want to keep multiple data in Excel cell's comment, I need to pack it into a single string and put it into the comment. When I want to read it, I will unpack it into different fields/variables to use. BitConverter totally skipped my mind, the shifting/copying can be avoided using this class. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want **ascii**,  i.e. "00" as **characters**, then just:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Ascii.GetBytes(length.ToString("00"));
```

or you could optimise it if you want.

But IMO, if you are storing 0-99, 1 byte is plenty:

```
byte b = (byte)length;
```

If you want the range 0-65535, then just:

```
bytes[0] = (byte)length;
bytes[1] = (byte)(length >> 8);
```

or swap index 0 and 1 for endianness.

But if you are using the full range (of either single or double byte), then it **isn't** ascii nor a string. Anything that tries to read it as a string might fail.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it's a good idea depends on the details of what it's for, but it's not *likely* to be good.

If you do this then you're no longer creating an "ASCII string". Those were your words, but maybe you don't really care whether it's ASCII.

You will sometimes get bytes with a value of 0 in your "string". If you're handling the strings with anything written in C, this is likely to cause trouble. You'll also get all sorts of other characters -- newlines, tabs, commas, etc. -- that may confuse software that's trying to work with your data.

The original plan of separating with (say) `|` characters will be more compact and easier for humans and software to read. The only obvious downsides are (1) you can't allow field values with a `|` in (or else you need some sort of escaping) and (2) parsing will be marginally slower.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get clever you could pack your 2 bytes into 1 where the value of byte 1 is <= 127, or if the value is >=128 you use 2 bytes instead. This technique looses you 1 bit, per byte that you are using, but if you normally have small values, but occasionally have larger values it dynamically grows to accommodate the value.

All you need to do is mark bit 8 with a value indicating that the 2nd byte is required to be read. 
If bit 8 of the active byte is not set, it means you have completed your value.

EG
If you have a value of 4 then you use this

```
|8|7|6|5|4|3|2|1|
|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|
```

If you have a value of 128 you then can read the 1st byte check if bit 8 is high, and read the remaining 7 bits of the 1st byte, then you do the same with the 2nd byte, moving the 7bits left 7 bits.

```
|BYTE 0         |BYTE 1         |
|8|7|6|5|4|3|2|1|8|7|6|5|4|3|2|1|
|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|
```